# Symmetric diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm going to draw a circular diagram like the follwoing:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[node distance=2mm]
>=stealth, auto,
every state/.style={draw=none,circle,node distance = 10cm}
]
\node[] (q1) {$1$};
\node[] (q2) [above right=of q1] {$a$};
\node[] (q3) [above right=of q2] {$ab$};
\node[] (q4) [below right=of q3] {$aba$};
\node[] (q5) [below right=of q4] {$(ab)^2$};
\node[] (q8) [below right=of q1] {$b$};
\node[] (q7) [below right=of q8] {$(ab)^3$};
\node[] (q6) [above right=of q7] {$(ab)^2a$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[bend left]%
\path[->]   (q1) edge node {} (q2)
(q2) edge node {} (q3)
(q3) edge node {} (q4)
(q4) edge node {} (q5)
(q6) edge node {} (q5)
(q6) edge node {} (q7)
(q7) edge node {}(q8)
(q8) edge node { } (q1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
```

But the result is not symmetric.
How can I modify it in order to get symmetric diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use polar coordinates (`(<angle>:<radius>)`) to place the nodes on a circle, instead of using the relative positioning. I used a loop in the code below, which shortens the code a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach [count=\i] \txt in {1,a,ab,aba,(ab)^2,(ab)^2a,(ab)^3,b}
   \node (q\i) at (-360/8*\i - 135: 2cm) {$\txt$};


\path[->, bend left=12]
  (q1) edge (q2)
  (q2) edge (q3)
  (q3) edge (q4)
  (q4) edge (q5)
  (q5) edge (q6)
  (q6) edge (q7)
  (q7) edge (q8)
  (q8) edge (q1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can i add a label in the middile of an edge?

Comment: @babgen The way you did in your original code. (I removed all the `node {}` after each `edge`, because empty nodes don't do anything.)  If you want the label to interrupt the arrow, use e.g. `(q1) edge node [fill=white] {a} (q2)`, if you want the label next to the arrow use e.g. `(q2) edge node [above] {b} (q3)` (alternatives to `above`: `left`, `right`, `below`, `above right`, etc.).

Comment: thaank you so much